# Can this be done with the TLP2368 optocoupler (open collector)? (Toshiba)

Tags: opto-isolator, open-collector

I have tried to write to Toshiba technical service, but no one responds.

I have the layout of this optocoupler (TLP2368).

[image]

According to the datasheets, the VCC voltage to GND is a maximum of 6V, so I will use a 5V LDO regulator.

But there is no information regarding the maximum voltage with respect to the collector and emitter when the transistor is off. (Vo regarding GND)

I want to connect a resistor to VO and the other terminal of the resistor to connect to 24 V, obviously the resistor will have a value that the current flowing through it is less than the maximum allowed.

Any idea if it is possible or would there be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

[This datasheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=7705&prodName=TLP2368) clearly states the maximum voltage for Vo to be 6V.

[image: Absolute maximum ratings for the part.]

Answer (score 0):

No that will not work.

The Vo pin maximum voltage is 6V, it's right there in the absolute maximum ratings.

Most likely that is why Toshiba technical support does not respond, as the answer is in the datasheet, and you would have to be a paying customer ordering thousands of these and even then the support request might go via proper business channels like through a distributor.

Comment: I would understand that that voltage is the maximum that can appear when the transistor conducts or when it is off similar to what I'm trying to do.

In other optocouplers the maximum VCE is indicated, but here it is confusing, since it only outputs VO

What would be the idea of an open collector if a load with a higher voltage cannot be handled?

I should buy a few and do some tests to see how it performs.

Comment: @user3249244 Here, it's called "VO" because the TLP2368 is not a simple phototransistor. But for you, the meaning is the same. VO actually can be larger than VCC, but it can never be larger than 6 V. Use the output to control a high-voltage transistor.

Comment: @user3249244 well that's a high speed isolator capable of 20 Mbps data transmission, so it would not make sense to use it for driving larger voltages that VCC. It's most likely identical to a sister model with digital push pull logic gate output, but configured to disable the high driver. The models with phototransistor output do have Vce listed so perhaps select another optocoupler that is suitable for your use.

Comment: I'm interested in using it to drive a P-type CMOS transistor with a PWM signal and with a duty cycle equal to 100 ns.

Comment: @user3249244 sounds like simply pulling the gate high with a resistor would have been too slow anyway. I think you need a gate driver. Some models include isolation as well.

Comment: I can't find a truly insulated gate driver. The ground of the pwm signal would be the ground of the circuit with the CMOS.